# How parse the text between the element of xml file in python

Tags: xml-parsing, python-3.6

I want to parse the xml file as following

```
  <book attr='1'>
  <page number='1'>
   <text> sss  </text>
   <text> <b>bb<i>sss<b></i></b></text>
   <text> <i><b>sss</b></i></text>
   <text><a herf='a'> sss</a></text>
  </page>
  <page number='2'>
   <text> sss2  </text>
   <text> <b>bb<i>sss2</i><b></text>
   <text> <i><b>sss2</b></i></text>
   <text><a herf='a'> sss2</a></text>
  </page>
   .......
  </book>
```

I want to extract all the text between the 'text'  element. But there are 'b' 'i' 'a' elements et al., in between the 'text' element.
I have tried to use the following code.

```
tree = ET.parse('book.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for p in root.findall('page'):
    print(p.get('number'))
    for t in p.findall('text'):
        print(t.text)
```

But the result:

```
 1
 sss
 None
 None
 None
  2
 sss2
 None
 None
 None
```

Actually, I want to extract all the text between the  and , and join to be sentence like the following:

```
  1
 bb sss
 sss
 sss
 sss
  2
 bb sss2
 sss2
 sss2
 sss2
```

But how to parse the subelement between the 'text' thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For parsing XML you can use BeautifulSoup. The text between elements can be obtained with `get_text()` method:

```
data = '''<book attr='1'>
  <page number='1'>
   <text> sss  </text>
   <text> <b>bb<i>sss<b></i></b></text>
   <text> <i><b>sss</b></i></text>
   <text><a herf='a'> sss</a></text>
  </page>
  <page number='2'>
   <text> sss2  </text>
   <text> <b>bb<i>sss2</i><b></text>
   <text> <i><b>sss2</b></i></text>
   <text><a herf='a'> sss2</a></text>
  </page>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for page in soup.select('page[number]'):
    print(page['number'])
    for text in page.select('text'):
        print(text.get_text(strip=True, separator=' '))
```

Prints:

```
1
sss
bb sss
sss
sss
2
sss2
bb sss2
sss2
sss2
```

Comment: could you don't use the beautiful soup since there is error when using the beautiful soup:FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?

Comment: @tktktk0711 Make sure you are using the latest version of `BeautifulSoup`. You can replace `lxml` parser for `html.parser` or 'html5lib`